# Webpack unknown option --display-optimization-bailout

Tags: webpack, optimization, build, webpack-5, webpack-cli

I upgraded from `webpack` `3.3.1` to `webpack-cli` `4.10.01

I am getting build error with `--display-optimization-bailout` in the command

Answer (score 0):

If you check the documentation for webpack 4 and 5 at following URL https://webpack.js.org/plugins/module-concatenation-plugin/#debugging-optimization-bailouts

It is visible that `--diplay-optimization-bailout` is changed to `--stats-optimization-bailout`